# Can JARs be uploaded successfully to AWS Elastic Beanstalk from the AWS web UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, maven, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, corretto

I'm trying to build a basic Spring Boot Java web app and deploy it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EB). Most tutorials I've read suggest uploading a JAR when creating an application, however, I'm unable to successfully deploy a JAR using the AWS web UI. When I try, the state of the environment is set as 'Severe' and the environment web link returns a 502 Bad Gateway response.

In order to make sure it wasn't some issue with the code, I downloaded the Java sample app from AWS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/samples/corretto.zip), fixed the jetty inconsistency in the pom.xml file (the plugin didn't match the dependency), set the JDK version to be the same as what I created the environment to be (Corretto 11), then ran the following command to create the JAR:

mvn package

When I upload the created JAR onto the EB environment, the deployment fails. If, however, I simply upload the downloaded zip file (with the corrected pom and correct JDK set), the deployment works.

The following AWS page talks about how to create a source bundle to upload and only mentions being able to upload ZIP and WAR files, not JARs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html

My question is then, is it possible to upload JAR files to Elastic Beanstalk via the EB web UI, or do I need to stick with WAR and ZIP files? This will help me when navigating the various Spring Boot / Elastic Beanstalk tutorials out there. It's proving quite difficult to get any Spring Boot web app to actually work on Elastic Beanstalk. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very possible to upload a JAR to Elastic Beanstalk using the AWS Management Console. Furthermore, then once deployed, the app shows Green:

[image]

If you get RED, means you have not set something correctly.

See this basic Spring BOOT app example to follow this process.

[Creating your first AWS Java web application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_first_project)

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much for you response. The step by step tutorial and code were extremely thorough. Excellent! As I'm a new member of Stack Overflow I'm unable to upvote your answer, but once I have enough Stack Overflow points to do so I'll return and upvote your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I appreciate it